# Install Raspbian OS on SD Card for Raspberry Pi

Tags: boot, sd-card, operating-systems, ubuntu

I am new with Raspberry Pi. I wrote the `.img` file onto my SD Card with DiskImager on Windows 7. I downloaded the `2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img` file from [the Raspberry Pi website](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).

When I start the Raspberry Pi device, some instructions appear on display and suddenly after a few seconds it starts again.  Then again it shows the same behavior.

I have version of Ubuntu 13.04 and I want to write `.img` file on SD Card. usb-imagewriter is not working for this. Can someone guide me to install Raspbian OS completely on my SD card?

I attached two picture,second picture show those instructions which execute and display. After these instruction , suddenly it restart again and show same behavior again and again.
[image: This picture show the Raspberry Pi in running state]

[image: Only these instruction appear and it suddenly restart]
Firstly I use my previous SD Card and then I purchase new SD Card pics given below:
[image: new SD Card]
[image: power cable]
I use new SD Card and power cable given in picture.

Comment: I changed the title to reflect what you ask in your question, but you changed it back so that they conflict.  What is your real question?  Do you want to install Raspbian, or Ubuntu?

Comment: My answer still covers both questions, so please take a look at it.

Comment: use photo or video camera to capture the error message that shows on the screen, and paste it (just type the text, we don't need the whole picture/video) into your question. that should help greatly.

Comment: The second picture is too far out and too blurry to discern the text easily.

Comment: @syb0rg i want to install any OS Raspbian or NOOBS but raspberry pi show the behavior which I discuss in above question. I don't understand weather it is problem with my .img file or raspberry Pi? But I make SD Card boot-able three times. One time through window 7 and two time with Ubuntu 13.04. I can't understand what I am suppose to do. Please if you have some other idea to make SD Card boot-able such that I successfully run OS on raspberry pi , you must guide me.

Comment: If you are using the same `.img` file all three times, then the image could have been corrupted during the download process.  If not, your SD card may be the issue at hand.  You may have to purchase a new one.  You can look if it is compatible with [this Raspberry Pi Wiki list](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards#Working_.2F_Non-working_SD_cards).  Also, make sure your power supply is providing sufficient power to the Raspberry Pi (5v/1000mA).

Comment: I have download .img twice of Raspbian OS and then one time for NOOBS from the same website: http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads

Comment: Is there problem with the class 4 of SD Card. Should it 10 class what you thick? Is this problem?

Comment: Even magnified that image is totally unreadable!  *What is the point in posting that?* If you can't be bothered to either post a **clearly readable** image, or copy it by hand, don't expect anyone to bother to help you.

Comment: @goldilocks u r right, i work on projector. i myself cant read these process they come in micro sec and again reboot if u send me ur email i can send u the video.

Comment: The power cable would not be the issue.  The power supply would be the issue.  Also, I need the SD card model number (something like `TS4GSDHC6`) to determine whether the SD card is at fault.

Comment: Try plugging it into a monitor or TV.  If you are saying it "reboots" after that message, **that is a bad sign.**  The kernel has obviously loaded, and the kernel *will not* reboot just because it failed (on the pi, it can't reboot even if it wanted to, because the pi has no "reboot" option -- all it could do is stop.  It can't even turn off the power.).  So: if the pi is restarting and booting over again, it's because there is a physical problem with the power.  It is momentarily dropping voltage, which makes it appear to restart (like flicking a power switch on and off).

Comment: **My power cable cause problem**. It show 4.3mA but it must between 4.7mA to 5.2mA.When I increase the rate of power ,it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have version of Ubuntu 13.04 and I want to write .img file on SD Card.

From linux it is pretty simple.  You get the zipped raspbian image from here (under "Raw Images", "Raspbian" -> "2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.zip").  Then:

```
unzip 2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.zip
```

Which leaves a file, `2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`.  Now, figure out which device node your SD card is. It will probably be, e.g., `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`.  It is *not* `/dev/sdb1` or `/dev/sdc2`, etc.  Those are partitions on a device -- you can tell because they end with a number.  **Do not write to a partition,** write to the entire device (`sdb`, not `sdb1`).

```
dd if=2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

That'll take a while.  When it's done, it's done.

Unfortunately, from the glimmer in the photo in your post, it looks like you did write an image and it did mostly boot.  What happened after that is unclear because the picture is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the NOOBS software.  It is easier than installing an OS manually.  All you need to do is:

1. Format your SD card using the SD Card Association’s [formatting tool](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/).
2. Download and unpack the [NOOBS zip file](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_latest) onto the SD card

---

There are multiple problems that could cause the error you are experiencing.  One of these problems could be a faulty SD card.  You should verify your SD card works with [this list](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards#Working_.2F_Non-working_SD_cards).  There could also be a problem with your power supply.  Make sure the power to your Raspberry Pi is [adequate to boot properly](http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#How_Can_I_tell_if_the_power_supply_is_inadequate.3F).  Another possibility is that your `.img` file was corrupted on download (this is the most unlikely, but is an option).

Comment: My power cable cause problem. It show 4.3mA but it must between 4.7mA to 5.2mA.When I increase the rate of power ,it works fine.